# (Datalife Engine) PHP Random Image Rotation picture is not showing up

Tags: php, css, datalife-engine

i have a problem with this roate.php.

I did everything like described here
[PHP Random Image Rotation](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/php_random_image_rotation.html) 
.But there picture showing up.
This is how my code look like.

style.css

```
.header_img {
overflow: hidden;
width: 1010px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 276px;
background: url(../header/rotate.php) no-repeat center 0;
border-width: 0 1px;
```

main.tpl

```
    <!-- /header --> 
</header>
<div id="header_img">
  <div class="header_img"><!-- no text --></div>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner, and that's all new to me.So i hope somebody can help me out here.

best regards

Comment: Open `rotate.php` in browser and check if php renders image correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is not problem on both rotate.php and dle script, but it's problem where to place "rotate.php" file location, you can't place any php files in your theme folder, it will be blocked by script and htaccess, so the solution is simple, create new folder in your root directory outside "templates" folder, example: "header" or "background"

Then place all images and rotate.php inside that folder so you can access to the folder and images like

```
http://your-domain.com/header/rotate.php
http://your-domain.com/header/image-1.php
http://your-domain.com/header/image-2.php
...
or
---
http://your-domain.com/background/rotate.php
http://your-domain.com/background/image-1.php
http://your-domain.com/background/image-2.php
```

Your main.tpl should be like this

```
<style type="text/css">
.header_img {
overflow: hidden;
width: 1010px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 276px;
background: url(/header/rotate.php) no-repeat center 0;
/* or */
/*
background: url(/background/rotate.php) no-repeat center 0;
*/
border-width: 0 1px;
</style>
    <!-- /header --> 
</header>
<div id="header_img">
  <div class="header_img"><!-- no text --></div>
</div>
```

Keep any php files out from "templates" folder. and do not place css in any css files, put all code in main.tpl.

Alternatively you can use this technique which we use in a few websites we did designs for them

1) Download rotator.txt from [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/articles/randomizer/), rename it rotator.php.

2) Put the images to be rotated in the same directory as rotator.php.

3) Upload all the files via FTP.

4) Add this code in main.tpl

```
<style type="text/css">
#rotator{
overflow: hidden;
width: 1010px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 276px;
background: url(/background/rotate.php) no-repeat center 0;
border-width: 0 1px;
</style>
    <!-- /header --> 
</header>
<div id="rotator">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: DLE has some issue for php file placing in templates folder, that must be the reason why rorate.php isn't working